# Loop over the JSON array below and display each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a homework assignment and I been trying to get Jquery to append my JSON file to the web page so it displays the objects in JSON like a list but all I get is "object" in my console I get the full json as an array and if I use alert not console log I get object

I tried some jquery methods for each and .append, I know we need to use Jquery just not sure what way, also tried ajax. I tried assigning the json file to a const variable and then appending that but just got an object , I want is a list of the object's key and value

json file

```
 [
    {      "category": "fruit",         
            "item": "apples",         
            "type": "Honey Crisp",         
            "brand": "Little cuties",         
            "qty": 10     
    }, 

    {   "category": "beverage",         
        "item": "milk", 
        "type": "2%",         
        "brand": "generic",         
        "qty": "1 gallon"     
    },   

    {   "category": "pasta",         
        "item": "Pasta",        
         "type": "Penne",         
         "brand": "Barilla",         
         "qty": 3     
    },   

 {  "category": "dessert",         
    "item": "Gelatin dessert",         
    "type": "Green",         
    "brand": "Jello",         
    "qty": 3     
},     

    {         
        "category": "dairy",         
        "item": "Yogurt",         
        "type": "Assorted flavors",         
        "brand": "Chobani",         
        "qty": 12     
        },

        {         
            "category": "pasta",         
            "item": "Pasta",         
            "type": "Linguini",         
            "brand": "Barilla",         
            "qty": 3     
            },     
        {         
            "category": "beverage",         
            "item": "Apple juice",         
            "type": "regular",         
            "brand": "Happy Farms",         
            "qty": 2     
            }, 

            {         
                "category": "beverage",         
                "item": "Vodka",         
                "type": "Tangerine",         
                "brand": "Grey Goose",
                "qty": 1
            }
]
```

basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Coding Project</title>

</head>

<body>


<script>



$.getJSON("groceries.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
    alert(json);
});

fetch.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200 ) {
        var groceries = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var output = '';
        for (var i=0, l=groceries.elements.length; i<l ; i++) {
            output += `
                <div>
                    <p>Name : ${groceries.elements[i].brand}</p>
                    <p>Symbol : ${groceries.elements[i].item}</p>
                    <p>Number : ${groceries.elements[i].qty}</p>
                    <p>Number : ${groceries.elements[i].category}</p>
                    <p>Number : ${groceries.elements[i].type}</p>
                </div> 
            `; 
        }
        $('.data').html(output);
    }
}






</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am able to get the json array in the console but I want it to append to the webpage, but so far I just get "object object object" appending to the webpage

Comment: Where is that `fetch` variable coming from? Seems like you're mixing jQuery with basic JS for ajax requests, which is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Object has inner jsons so you need to loop at second level. Like this:

```js
let myJson = [
            {
                category: "fruit",
                item: "apples",
                type: "Honey Crisp",
                brand: "Little cuties",
                qty: 10
            },

            {
                category: "beverage",
                item: "milk",
                type: "2%",
                brand: "generic",
                qty: "1 gallon"
            },

            {
                category: "pasta",
                item: "Pasta",
                type: "Penne",
                brand: "Barilla",
                qty: 3
            },

            {
                category: "dessert",
                item: "Gelatin dessert",
                type: "Green",
                brand: "Jello",
                qty: 3
            },

            {
                category: "dairy",
                item: "Yogurt",
                type: "Assorted flavors",
                brand: "Chobani",
                qty: 12
            },

            {
                category: "pasta",
                item: "Pasta",
                type: "Linguini",
                brand: "Barilla",
                qty: 3
            },
            {
                category: "beverage",
                item: "Apple juice",
                type: "regular",
                brand: "Happy Farms",
                qty: 2
            },

            {
                category: "beverage",
                item: "Vodka",
                type: "Tangerine",
                brand: "Grey Goose",
                qty: 1
            }
        ];

        $.each(myJson, function(i, item){
            let paragraph = $("<p>"),
                imgSrc = '';

            switch(item.category) {
                case 'fruit':
                    imgSrc = 'https://www.iheartnaptime.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/honey-lime-fruit-salad-i-heart-naptime-3-200x200.jpg';
                    break;
                case 'beverage':
                    imgSrc = 'https://tiimg.tistatic.com/categoryimg/v1/1/beverages-399.jpg';
                    break;
                case 'pasta':
                    imgSrc = 'https://danzadefogones.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Pasta-con-Ajo-y-Aceite.jpg';
                    break;
                case 'dairy':
                    imgSrc = 'https://paleoleap.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/dairy2-s.jpg';
                    break;
            }

            paragraph.append('<img src="'+ imgSrc +'" width="100"><br/>');

            $.each(item, function(j, property) {
                paragraph.append('<b>' + j + ':</b> ' + property + '<br />')
            });

            $("body").append(paragraph)
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this, I have a follow up, I want to make it so every "category" in json opens an image too, its extra credit. so like category fruit would have an image open up next to it or under it, can you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Done, take a look at the code again. I used images from sites I found in the Internet. You should store your own images in a folder within your project

Comment: thanks alot, sorry if I asked a super noob question, I am really trying to learn. I am super thankful you didnt give me a side remark but actually helped me if you have any supplemental materials you believe helped you learn this that you believe could help I am open to it but ya super thankful for you help